# Incoming calls from a contact are involuntarily blocked

Tags: calls

Recently, I don't get any notifications about a call from a contact. The only thing I see is that the call has been blocked when I look into the caller list, see image.

[image]

Please not the  Icon under the call entry. I am not aware that I've block this contact nor can I see the number in the blocked contact. Is this an issue with Android? How can I fix this to *get calls from this contact*? On the other hand I can perfectly call this contact but the other way it does not work.

Google Android 14.

Comment: Go the settings of the phone app you use, there will be a category/section related to blocked contacts. It will list all blocked contacts. You can remove the contact from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following worked, I got back the calls from my contact. Though, I am not sure whether this is a bug. For the screenshots I've changed the language to English.

Going to "Settings" -> "Notifications" -> (General) "Do Not Disturb" -> "People", I have set my contact to be the person that can interrupt me.

After I've removed

[image]

[image]

The thing I've changed was to set from "Starred contact" to "Anyone". This solved my issue and I could answer calls from my contact.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By the look of your image, you are using Google's Phone app.

1. Press the 3-dot, then Settings.
2. On the General section, select "Blocked numbers".
3. All blocked numbers will be listed. Unselect the number(s) that you mustn't be blocked.

Or

1. Press on the contact's name. A menu should appear showing: "Send a message", "Unblock", "Call details".
2. Select "Unblock".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, it's Google's Phone app. I've already checked that "Blocked numbers" section but this list is empty. Your second suggestions shows also that the contact isn't blocked, i.e. this gives me only the opportunity to block this contact.

Comment: So the app is showing that the contact is blocked on the history, but it is not on the blocked list?

Comment: Yes, it seems like that: in the caller list (screenshot) the contact has this  icon which I interpret as *blocked*. But the contact does *not* appear in the blocked numbers list.

Comment: What do you see when you press on "Call details"? Does it show the contact's number or not?

Comment: Yes, in that case I see the number. I am not aware of any changes I've done on the phone. Though, I haven't tried that others call me. Whether only this number is blocked or all calls 

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Google's application, I would check both the OEM's phone application as well as the carrier's.

A few additional things to note:

- The carrier's app may not necessarily be installed on the device but can still be actively blocking calls; for example, T-Mobile default deployment has certain phone numbers, e.g., incarceration facilities or the District Attorney's office, actively blocked out-the-box.  You also don't technically *need* to use the application for the carrier side, as you can manage everything through MMI codes as well.
- I've experienced some buggy behavior with OEM blocking before, and what I found to work reliably was to **explicitly** define high-value numbers in whitelist (in addition to checking they aren't on blacklist).  Depending on the OEM, this may be referred to as Favorites, VIP's, Allowlist, etc.